# Retrieving Result From Database

Tags: php, sql, regex

Here is my table structure:

```
Table Call_Log

id | StationId | LoginId |  keystroke | timestamp
```

I need to be able to find how many times key '`1`' was pressed after key '`5`' in between key presses '`Q`'.

```
EX: 'Q','5','1','Q' will return true
but 'Q','5','2','Q' will return false
```

Also, I need to do in a manner so that I can add more keys to the find column and it finds them as well. So if I wanted to look for key `3` after '`5`' and '`1`', it can do similar.

```
Ex: 'Q','5','1','3','Q' will return true
but 'Q','5','1','2','Q' will return false
```

Comment: Please tell me you're not logging every single keystroke in a mysql database.

Comment: Can you put a time constraint on your search?  If you could put a time constraint on the search this would be easily feasible with a FSA.  As this is just an FSA question.

Comment: Can you post code that you have tried?

Comment: @Walkerneo +10 If you are really recording each keystroke in the database, please read a couple of articles about databases, optimization and best practices before you waste your time developing the application.

Comment: is `keystroke` separated by `,` and enclosed by `'` ?

Comment: How are we supposed to know the encoding of these keystrokes?!  I propose taking the control code produced by each keystroke and storing a bitmask of the number represented by the keystroke.  It's the only way to be safe.

Comment: Is `keystroke` a `CHAR(1)` column? Or can it hold multiple keystrokes?

Comment: Wait, I know!  Have a `bit_lookup` table with two columns: `bit_id` (primary key) and `bit` (with datatypes `smallint` and `bit(1)`, respectively).  Then you can have a `keystroke_lookup` table with `keystroke_id` (primary key), `bit_id` (foreign key referring to `bit_lookup`) and `bit_rank` (so that we can determine the order of bits for a particular keystroke).  We can also have a `keystroke_name` table with columns `keystroke_id` (foreign key corresponding to the `keystroke_lookup` table) and `keystroke` (of datatype char(1)).  Then all other tables can refer to `keystroke_id`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (
  SELECT
    IF(
      @matchstring='Q' AND keystroke='5', 
      @matchsting:='Q5',
      IF(
        @matchstring='Q5' AND keystroke='1',
        @matchstring:='Q51',
        IF (@matchstring='Q51' AND keystroke='Q',
          @matchstring:='Q51Q',
          @matchstring:=keystroke
        )
      )
    ) AS matchpart
  FROM
    (SELECT @matchstring:=''),
    Call_Log
  WHERE
    -- Your criteria here, might be "StationID=blah"
  ORDER BY
    Call_Log.`timestamp`
) AS baseview
WHERE matchpart='Q51Q'
;
```